# How to get string from variable in Xposed?

Tags: java, android, xposed

I want to get a string from a variable. The smali looks like this:

```
.method protected Init()V
    .locals 1

    .line 121
    const-string v0, "hello.." <= i want to get this string

    invoke-static {p0, v0}, Ldha/ˌ;->ˊ(Landroid/content/Context;Ljava/lang/String;)Ldha/ˌ;

    move-result-object v0

    iput-object v0, p0, Lcom/xxx/xxx/Activity;->mx:Ldha/ˌ;

    return-void
.end method
```

What method should I use?

Answer (score 0):

The smallest hookable "unit" in Xposed is the method. You cannot access/replace instructions inside of a method - you must hook the method as a whole.

What you can do instead is hook the function which is called with the string as a parameter:

```
invoke-static {p0, v0}, Ldha/ˌ;->ˊ(Landroid/content/Context;Ljava/lang/String;)Ldha/ˌ;
```

The string you are interested in is passed as the second argument to this static method.